# Notepad++ and RegEx, how to reorder a numbered list

Tags: regex, notepad++

The text on each line is different and the only thing common to every text block is that they are numbered. The biggest problem is some of the lines continue to a new line with another number adjacent to it (ie: line 2). How can I organize this from 1-10 in proper order with a single line for each line text?

If someone can please provide a regex solution in notepad++ or any other app, I would highly appreciate it.

```html
1. line 1 random text                  6. line 6 random text 
2. line 2 random text                  7. line 7 random text 
   continuation of line 2              8. line 8 random text
3. line 3 random text                  9. line 9 random text 
4. line 4 random text                  10. line 10 random text
5. line 5 random text
```

Comment: This is not a problem that you can solve with regex. You could write a little script to handle it, though.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. To answer the question as stated may take a significant amount of effort. You need to show some effort into solving the problem yourself before you can expect much assistance from us. Please explain what methods you have tried and describe how well they worked. As it stands your question is likely to be voted down and closed as being too vague and not providing enough information about what you have tried. See also the help link (at the top of this page) about what sort of question can be asked here on Stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps. First use a regex to join the lines, something like replace `\R[ \t]+` with a single space. This assumes continuation lines start with a space or a tab. Next use the TextFX plugin to sort the lines. You may need an intermediate step to add some leading zeros so that each line starts with the same number of digits.

Comment: If I join the continuing line with its parent it will not work since there's another numbered line in between. In example above 2 and 7 are on the same line separated by spaces. If I join the continuing line 2 it will merge with 7.